# Why is the bootstrap dropdown not working by using button as option?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
 </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want something like dropdown list and the option with button tag. e.g https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_js&stacked=h

I want to replace the anchor tag with button, but it will displayed as button shape which i don't want it to be. I tried the code in https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/ , but it doesn't displayed as what it looks like. Any way to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will work for you.**

**Updated**

I just added some extra **CSS custom style** to support your `buttons`, this is needed because as **default** the style is supported for `.dropdown-menu>li>a` that means the style will only support the `a` tag inside the `li` under the `.dropdown-menu`, so what I did was - I just styled your button to the **default style**.

I have also added `<span class="caret"></span>` to the <kbd>Dropdown</kbd> button and also added the class `btn-primary` use this only if its needed. Hope this helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu>button.dropdown-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown-menu>button.dropdown-item:focus,
.dropdown-menu>button.dropdown-item:hover {
  color: #262626;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is it the same way to do it if i am using the sample show in first link?

Comment: When i use the css style why it will affect the data table font etc?

Comment: @Zidance No. I have targeted only to the `button`'s inside the `.dropdown-menu`. there will be no issues.

Comment: Ikr. But there is an issue with my data table when apply this css, where the font became bigger.

Comment: I have updated the **CSS** for you for better button targeting. Hope it helps.